# problem when I try add a struct to other struct and use the free function

Tags: c, struct, free

I created a function in C called 'remover' that is used to remove a struct of the array 'lista'. This function resizes 'lista'. The problem is that I tried to print the elements of 'lista' but it prints strange things.
When I don't free 'lista_aux' the program runs normally. Why does it happen?

```
typedef struct localidade{
    char nome[31];
    float local[3];
}Localidade;

Localidade** remover(Localidade** lista, char end_remover[], int posicao){
    int i, j;
    int pos_remover;
    char nome_aux[31];
    Localidade** lista_aux;
    lista_aux = (Localidade**) malloc((posicao) * sizeof(Localidade*));
    if( lista_aux == NULL){
        printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for( i = 0; i < posicao; i++){
        lista_aux[i] = (Localidade*) malloc(sizeof(Localidade));
        if( lista_aux[i] == NULL){
        printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!\n");
        exit(-1);
        }
    }
    for( i = 0; end_remover[i]; i++ ){
        end_remover[i] = toupper( end_remover[i] );
    }
    for( i = 1; i < posicao; i++){
        strcpy( nome_aux, lista[i]->nome);
        for( j = 0; nome_aux[j]; j++){
            nome_aux[j] = toupper( nome_aux[j] );
        }
        if( !(strcmp( end_remover, nome_aux)) ){
            pos_remover = i;
            break;
        }
        else if( i == posicao ){
            printf("Endereco nao cadastrado.\n");
        }
    }
    for( i = 0; i < posicao; i++){
        if( i < pos_remover ){
            lista_aux[i] = lista[i];
        }
        else{
            lista_aux[i] = lista[i + 1];
        }
        //printf("***%s\n", lista_aux[i]->nome);
    }
    lista = (Localidade**) realloc( lista, (posicao)*sizeof(Localidade*));
    lista = lista_aux;
    //printf("*****%s\n", lista[1]->nome);
    /*for( i = 0; i < posicao; i++ ){
        printf("***%s\n", lista[i]->nome);
    }
    for( i = 0; i < posicao; i++ ){
        printf("*****%s\n", lista_aux[i]->nome);
    }*/
    /*for( i = 0; i < posicao; i++){
        free( lista_aux[i] );
    }
    free( lista_aux );*/

    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Select the code and press CTRL+K to format it properly. There's a preview window. Use it!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (well, one of them) appears to lie here:

```
lista = (Localidade**) realloc( lista, (posicao)*sizeof(Localidade*));
lista = lista_aux;
```

This does *not* copy everything at `lista_aux` to `lista`, it just changes the `lista` pointer to point to the `lista_aux` data (overwriting the memory you just reallocated).

If you then free that data, your pointer is left pointing at freed memory.

You don't need to copy the memory if you've created a brand new array, you should just free the original and return the copy you made:

```
free (lista);
lista = lista_aux;
```

---

There's a better way to do what you're attempting by doing it in-place. It's a simpler form which simply uses a source and destination index to remove unwanted elements.

Normally, source and destination will be identical so that the array doesn't change but, when a removable item is found, the source is incremented *without* the destination (after freeing the data for the unwanted element of course).

I've also changed it so it gives you back the new size as well. Here's a complete program, test suite and all:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct localidade {
    char nome[31];
    float local[3];
} Localidade;

static void dump ( int sz, Localidade **lista) {
    int i;

    printf ("Size = %d\n", sz);
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        printf ("   [%s]\n", lista[i]->nome);

}
```

```
Localidade **remover (
    Localidade **lista,
    char end_remover[],
    int posicao,
    int *new_posicao)
{
    int sidx, didx;

    // Maintain separate source and destination indexes.

    sidx = didx = 0;
    while (sidx < posicao) {
        // If need to remove, just increment source after freeing.

        if (stricmp (end_remover, lista[sidx]->nome) == 0) {
            free (lista[sidx]);
            lista[sidx++] = NULL;
            continue;
        }

        // Otherwise transfer and increment both indexes.

        lista[didx++] = lista[sidx++];
    }

    *new_posicao = didx;
    if (sidx != didx)
        lista = realloc (lista, (*new_posicao) * sizeof(Localidade*));
    return lista;
}
```

```
int main (void) {
    int sz;

    Localidade **x = malloc (3 * sizeof(Localidade*));
    x[0] = malloc (sizeof(Localidade));
    x[1] = malloc (sizeof(Localidade));
    x[2] = malloc (sizeof(Localidade));
    sz = 3;
    strcpy (x[0]->nome, "PaxDiablo");
    strcpy (x[1]->nome, "Adriano");
    strcpy (x[2]->nome, "Kate Bush");

    dump (sz, x);

    x = remover (x, "AdRiAnO", sz, &sz);
    dump (sz, x);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs, as expected:

```
Size = 3
   [PaxDiablo]
   [Adriano]
   [Kate Bush]
Size = 2
   [PaxDiablo]
   [Kate Bush]
```

Comment: A memory leak and doing things yourself where there's a perfectly good library function (`stricmp` for case-insensitive string comparisons).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really a expert!!!But in some months I will programing much much better than you!(it's a joke).

Answer (score 1):

If you free lista_aux, your code will be returning an invalid (freed) pointer to the caller, because of this line:

```
lista = lista_aux;
```

Your code has other issues (depending on how you call it, you may have a memory leak, for starters) and I'd suggest you review your algorithm for removing an entry from "lista". One suggestion would be to have a known size for the list (or a NULL-terminated list), and using memmove() instead of manually copying things around.